# How to retrieve the InMemoryUserDetailsManager instance in a Spring application?

Tags: java, spring-security

Assuming one is using the default in-memory security of Spring in an application, how can the `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` instance be retrieved in the code?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply inject it with `@Autowire`:

```
@Autowired
private InMemoryUserDetailsManager userDetailsManager;
```